# Storing ID from SQL result

Tags: sql, vb.net, executereader

Im running the following code to tell if a user excists on a database - standard stuff. Obviously once the code is run a boolean true or false will be returned if there is a result. If a result is found i want to store the ID of the said result. Can anyone tell me how'd id go about doing this?

code:

```
 Username = txtUserName.Text
    Password = txtPassword.Text
    dbConnInfo = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source = C:\Users\Dave\Documents\techs.mdb"
    con.ConnectionString = dbConnInfo
    con.Open()
    Sql = "SELECT * FROM techs WHERE userName =  '" & Username & "' AND '" & Password & "'"
    LoginCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(Sql, con)
    CheckResults = LoginCommand.ExecuteReader
    RowsFound = CheckResults.HasRows
    con.Close()
    If RowsFound = True Then

        MsgBox("Details found")

        TechScreen.Show()
    Else
        MsgBox("Incorrect details")
    End If
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of problems with the code snippet you posted. Hopefully, I can help you correct these problems.

In order to load the ID of the result you'll want to use [SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) as this is optimized to pull back one result from Sql.

As to what is wrong with your code, you're wide open to Sql Injection attacks and you should be using [Parametrized Queries](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Defense_Option_1%3a_Prepared_Statements_.28Parameterized_Queries.29) as shown in my sample below.

```
Public Function AddProductCategory( _
  ByVal newName As String, ByVal connString As String) As Integer 
    Dim newProdID As Int32 = 0
    Dim sql As String = _
     "INSERT INTO Production.ProductCategory (Name) VALUES (@Name); " _
       & "SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int);" 

Using conn As New SqlConnection(connString)
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, conn)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar)
    cmd.Parameters("@Name").Value = newName
    Try
        conn.Open()
        newProdID = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
    End Try 
End Using 

Return newProdID
End Function
```

Source: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx)